# Android studioにRunが2個ありますが違いは?

Tags: android, android-studio

初心者です。簡単な内容かもしれませんが、
以下の画像にある"Run"と"Run..."の違いは何でしょうか?
前者がグレーアウトされているため、やむなく後者を選んでますが・・・

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

デフォルトの実行/デバッグ構成を使用して実行する場合は「**Run**」を
実行構成を選択してから実行したい場合は「**Run...**」になるようです。

参考：
[実行、デバッグ構成の作成と編集 | Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html?hl=ja)